# Over vs during - difference in whether it lasts up to the present?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, time

I have read the following: we use over when something last up to the present /or future/ and we use during for a definite period of time.

So is this wrong?

> I worked in the company IBM over the last Summer.
>
> I was studying for the exam over Octover and November.  //lets say it is January

Acco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I worked in the company IBM over the last Summer.

This is wrong.  The 'last' is implied and out of place.  Also , 'in the company IBM' is awkward as well.  It should just be:

> I worked for IBM over the summer.

For the second sentence:

> I was studying for the exam over Octover and November. //lets say it is January

This is, if not wrong, at least unusual.  I don't think I've ever heard anyone use 'over' with named months likes. That would be when you want to use 'during':

> I was studying for the exam during October and November.

Comment: I would have said the second example was an ideal opportunity to use *during* (*I was studying for the exam during October and November*). The expression *over the summer* doesn't quite work in Britain, not because we differ in the way *over* is used - but this is a particular use of the term *summer* which is peculiar to Americans. But I'm going to address a separate question on this topic - so watch this space.

Comment: @WS2 good point.  I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks. For the "in the company X" - I was taught that when I use "company" and a name, the order is "company NAME". But mainly my question was whether the distinction between those words as I mentioned is correct.

Comment: +1) for suggesting "during" for "over".